# why does the 'else if ' part of my code not show what is between the 'else if ' braces?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Trying to make code here to store a pin number and ask the user to enter in the correct pin number. The user has 3 attempts and every time they get it wrong it should say you have 2 attempts remaining etc. And when correct should say you have entered the correct pin.

I can figure out why my `else if(guess== pin)` wont show whats in its braces, it just keeps on looping and asking to enter a 4 digit code. Help would be appreciated!

```
int pin = 1234;
int guess = 0;
int count;


if (guess != pin)
{
    for (count = 2; count > -1; count-- )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a 4 digit pin number");
        guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        if(guess != pin)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect pin number, you have {0}   attempts remaining", count);
        }

    }
}
else if (guess == pin)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct pin number");
}

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: well... the if/else ought to probably be in the loop if you want to execute it more than once.  (Or once on success for the else should go with inner if)

Comment: have you tried Debug your app in step-by-step mode?

Comment: Please reign in the whitespace and extra blank lines. Second, you loop if wrong pin, and you would never ever get to the code in `else if (guess == pin)` unless they enter it right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've created a logical condition where it will never happen.  Simplified, this is your code:

```
int pin = 1234;
int guess = 0;
if (guess != pin)
{

}
else if (guess == pin)
{

}
```

You've *explicitly* set `pin` and `guess` to different values, and then *immediately* compare them.  Since that first comparison will *always* pass, the `else if` block will never be evaluated.

I'm sure there are lots of ways to make this comparison, but one simple change you can make is to move your logic to within the loop where you accept the user input and then `break` from the loop when a correct number is entered.  Something like this:

```
if(guess != pin)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect pin number, you have {0}   attempts remaining", count);
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct pin number");
     break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code enters the first if and then loops for three times, but the test for the correct pin number is outside the loop.

The for loop should contain your if tests and, because you have only two possible response, you don't really need and `else if`, a simple `else` will do.
Notice also, that if you have typed the correct pin number, you should exit the for loop....

```
    int pin = 1234;
    int guess = 0;
    int count;


    for (count = 2; count > -1; count-- )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a 4 digit pin number");
        guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



        if(guess != pin)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("");
             Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect pin number, you have {0}   attempts remaining", count);
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct pin number");
           break;
        }
    }


    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring your `else if` inside the loop. 
Add a `break` statement to exit from loop in case you don't want to ask for another input if first attempt is correct:

```
 if (guess != pin)
    {
        for (count = 2; count > -1; count-- )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a 4 digit pin number");
            guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(guess != pin)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect pin number, you have {0}   attempts remaining", count);
            }
            else if (guess == pin)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct pin number");
                 break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your control flow is just wrong, you're reading the input inside a loop and the `else if` is outside of that.

Instead try this;

```
            for (count = 2; count > -1; count-- )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a 4 digit pin number");
                guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



                if(guess != pin)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect pin number, you have {0}   attempts remaining", count);
                }
                else if (guess == pin)
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct pin number");
                }

            }
```

I simply moved the else if inside the loop so that it gets checked each time the user enters something. Also, there is no need for an `elseif`, you ahve `if(guess != pin)` if that evaluates to false then guess must be equal to pin so simple `else` will work just fine. Else-if is only required when you're checking between more than 2 outcomes. If there are only 2 possible outcomes than a simple if-else makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use condition in `while` loop and with some modification your code should look like:

```
int pin = 1234;
int guess = 0;
int count = 3;

while (guess != pin && count > 0)
{
    Console.Write("Enter a 4 digit pin number: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out guess);
    if (guess != pin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("You entered an incorrect pin number, you have {0}   attempts remaining", count - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered the correct pin number");
    }
    count--;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```